# Query field changing abnormally changing with Chrome

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome

I have a project I am working on, it is in a limited access environment on a LAMP server. The script I am having trouble with updates the database on page refresh with the logged in user's current page and a timestamp. However in Chrome, the page variable is being changed to the string 'nopage' The mysql field is a tinytext field with no default set. I modified the code just for testing and pinpointing the problem:

So on page 'home'

```
echo $thePage;
//outputs home

$sql_in = "
UPDATE     `users` 
SET        idle='".$config['time']."', 
           last_page_visit='".$thePage."' 
WHERE      username='".$row['username']."' 
LIMIT 1 ";

echo $sql_in;
```

outputs:

```
'UPDATE     `users` 
SET         idle='1375975152', 
            last_page_visit='home' 
WHERE       username='Admin' 
LIMIT 1'
```

---

```
$dbcnx->query($sql_in );
exit();
```

Here is the weird thing. The first echo outputs the page correctly, such as 'home' and the last echo outputs the correct sql with 'home' for the variable for all browsers (I know, browser should not matter here). But, when I use Chrome, it always enters the string 'nopage' for the last_page_visit field in the database. I cannot figure out why it would echo correctly, but change in the database only when using Chrome.

I put the exit in so I am sure no other code is being executed after this. Also I searched my whole project for the string 'nopage' and it is not found. The variable $thePage is getting the value from $_GET['home'], so I could see Chrome reporting the wrong value to the list of $_GET variables, but it is echoing out correct. When I replace the variable for last_page_visit with a string, the database will correctly record whatever I put in it. I do not know what else to try.

Comment: Can you change the query to `last_page_visit='abc-".$thePage."'`? So you'll know if `last_page_visit` was set with this script. It might also help to log each access to this page by logging to a file, maybe Chrome is doing more requests than you expect.

Comment: This makes your code vulnerable to [`SQL-Injection`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!

Comment: Do you have any functions or other variables interacting with `$thePage` can you post your functions or variables in use on it if any ? Are you passing it from page to page are you setting it on a link ? have you checked if it was not empty when u got nopage ?

Comment: @Frits van Campen Yes I tried this, it would put abc- in front of 'nopage' so somehow the variable is being changed when the query is ran. I will try logging each as new row.

Comment: It's possible the value is being set from elsewhere.

Comment: @Markus - This is on a closed system, and not the issue.

Comment: @Frits You are onto something... Chrome is logging 2 entries, the first being correct and the second with 'nopage' Now I just need to figure out why.

Comment: Try to find where "nopage" is coming from. Maybe it's composite like: `$a = "no"; $b = "page"; $page = $a.$b;`

Comment: @EGriff Aha, but do you trust the users in the `closed system`? It doesn't hurt if you still encode / escape the $thePage value. Did you read about prepared statements yet? Do you use MySQLi?

Comment: @markus yes using mysqli and escaping. I do use PDO some, still getting use to the format

Comment: Solved I think. Every access Chrome sends a second request to a page that does not exist and htaccess is forwarding to 'nopage' I put in a check for nopage and exit if true and all is well. Going to look at server logs to see what Chrome is looking for. Thank you all

Comment: Chrome was looking for a favicon.

Comment: @EGriff **Great you solved the problem.** _Problems like this can cost a lot of time and nerves._